# AJAX select filtering in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I try to filter data in my view using select box. I'm using CodeIgniter and I want to filter it using AJAX. I already test the code and look at the console, and AJAX post returns a result. The problem is, I don't know how to display the result in my view. I mean, how am I suppose to write in `success: function(){}`?

This is my AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectBerdasar").change(function() {
        var key = $(this).val();
        console.log(key);
        var postdata = {key: key};
        var url = '<?php echo site_url('produk/filter/GetFilterJson');?>';
        $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                $('col-item').empty();
                $.each(obj, function(key, line) {

                });
            } else {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <select class="form-control" id="selectBerdasar">
            <!--  <option>Produk Terbaru</option>
            <option>Produk Terpopuler</option> -->
            <option value="termahal">Harga Termahal</option>
            <option value="termurah">Harga Termurah</option>
            <option value="alfabet">Alfabet A-Z</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($produk as $data) {?>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="col-item">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('produk/item/detail/' . $data['id_produk']);?>">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/user/img/produk/<?php echo $data['gambar'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="price col-md-12">
                                <h5><?php echo $data['nama_produk'];?></h5>
                                <h5 class="price-text-color">Rp.<?=number_format($data['harga_produk'], 0, ',', '.')?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I just don't know how to display the result in my view.

Comment: have you tried using `.html(line.some_name)`  inside your ajax `success`? Where in your view do you want the results?

Comment: inside tag "col-item". Can you give me code example please...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Codeigniter, I would use a different approach. This approach will let you modify the html separately in a template under the views directory.

Basically, we will build three function methods. The first method `products()` takes care of the initial page, it will retrieve all the products from the model, then send the products to the second method `buildProdHTML($prods)` to build the data as html, lastly it will send the html to the view `view.php`, where the select dropdown and jquery resides. The jquery/ajax will use the third method `GetFilteredProducts()`; this method will retrieve the filtered products from the database, build the HTML, and send it back to jquery.

Here's what I mean:

Controller:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function GetFilteredProducts() {
        $key = $this->input->post("key");
        $prods = $this->model_name->getProductsByKey($key);//Assuming you are using the function result();
        if ($prods) {
            $html = $this->buildProdHTML($prods);
            echo $html;
        }
    }

    private function buildProdHTML($prods) {
        $html = $this->load->view("templates/product", array("products" => $prods), TRUE);
        return $html;
    }

    public function products() {
        $prods = $this->model_name->getProducts(); //Assuming you are using the function result();
        if ($prods) {
            $html = $this->buildProdHTML($prods);
            $this->load->view("view", array('prod_html' => $html));
        }
    }
}
```

views/view.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <select class="form-control" id="selectBerdasar">
            <!--  <option>Produk Terbaru</option>
            <option>Produk Terpopuler</option> -->
            <option value="1">Harga Termahal</option>
            <option value="2">Harga Termurah</option>
            <option value="alfabet">Alfabet A-Z</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="results" class="row">
    <?= $prod_html?>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selectBerdasar").change(function() {
            var postdata = { key: $(this).val() };
            var url = '<?= site_url('site/GetFilteredProducts'); ?>';
            $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    $('#results').html(result);
                } else {

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

views/templates/product.php

```
<?php foreach ($products as $data) { ?>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-item">
            <a href="<?= base_url('produk/item/detail/' . $data->id_produk); ?>">
                <div class="photo">
                    <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>asset/user/img/produk/<?= $data->gambar; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="price col-md-12">
                            <h5><?= $data->nama_produk; ?></h5>
                            <h5 class="price-text-color">Rp.<?= number_format($data->harga_produk, 0, ',', '.') ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you to should to numerate your items like this:

```
<?php foreach ($produk as $KEY => $data) ?>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div id="id-<?= $KEY ?>" class="col-item">
```

where $KEY is your id of data's element (you may use $data['key'] variant

Then use something like:

```
// ... 
var someHtml = ''; 
obj.forEach(function(elem, index) { 
   // remember to convert data type to string
   someHtml = '<p>'+elem.some_data_to_display + '</p>'; 
   $('#id-'+elem.key).html(someHtml); 
});
```

// ...